# How do I pass a variable to a function that satisfies a ValidateSet?

Tags: powershell, dbatools

I am calling the dbatools `Install-DbaInstance` function, and one of the parameters is `Feature`.  I initialize the variable to "Engine".  If `$bolSSIS -eq $true`, I want to add "IntegrationServices" to the variable. If `$bolSSAS -eq $true`, I want to add "AnalysisServices" to the variable.

The code below is not complete, but I believe is enough to explain what I'm trying to do:

```
$bolSSIS = $true
$bolSSAS = $false
$InstallFeatures = "Engine"
if ($bolInstallFeatureSSIS -eq $true) { $InstallFeatures += ",IntegrationServices" }
if ($bolInstallFeatureSSAS -eq $true) { $InstallFeatures += ",AnalysisServices" }

Install-DbaInstance -Feature $InstallFeatures
```

The code above returns the error:
`Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Feature'. The argument "Engine,IntegrationServices" does not belong to the set "Default,All,Engine,Tools,Replication,FullText,DataQuality,PolyBase,MachineLearning,AnalysisServices,IntegrationServices, {others removed for brevity} " specified by the ValidateSet attribute. Supply an argument that is in the set and then try the command again.`

Here's my question: How do I set `$InstallFeatures`?

I've tried strings, arrays, hashes, and other variable types.

FWIW, if `$InstallFeatures` is set to only "Default", the `Install-DbaInstance -Feature $InstallFeatures` command works and does not return an error.

Answer (score 2):

If you declare $InstallFeatures as an array, adding more strings will add them as array elements rather than concatenating.

e.g

```
$boolSSIS = $true
$boolSSAS = $false
$InstallFeatures = @("Engine")
if ($boolSSIS) { $InstallFeatures += "IntegrationServices" }
if ($boolSSAS) { $InstallFeatures += "AnalysisServices" }
```

Answer (score 2):

Parameter `Feature` is defined as string array (`[string[]]$Feature`). You are sending a single string where it should be an array.

Without changing the rest of your script, you could do

```
Install-DbaInstance -Feature ($InstallFeatures -split ',')
```